# Is it inefficient to use count() in Laravel Blade?

Tags: laravel

This is more a "best practice" question.

My website has articles, and articles can have comments.

```
public function comments() {
    return $this->hasMany('App\Comment', 'submission_id');
}
```

On the front page, where the articles are listed, the amount of comments are shown:

```
@if ($article->comments->count())
    {{ $article->comments->count() }}
    {{ $article->comments->count() == 1 ? 'comment' : 'comments' }}
@endif
```

And I was thinking to myself, in this example, is my database being queried 3 times for this simple code snippet?

Every time I get the comment count through this relationship, is it loading the entire array of comments and all of its columns? Because sometimes articles can have upwards of 1k+ comments.

If so, would it not be best practice to simply have a column in my `articles` database table that increments every time a comment is posted and then fetching that directly rather than through the relationship?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not the way you're doing it. It depens on when you're using `->count()`, and whether or not it's the `Collection` version, or the `Builder` version. See the following examples:

Example one - new query with `comments()` method:

```
$article = Article::first();
$article->comments()->count();
```

In this example, using `$article->comments()` causes a new query to be started (using the `Builder` class). No matter how you finish this query, i.e. using `->first()`, `->get()` or `->count()` a new query will be executed.

Now, example two - new query with `comments` property:

```
$article = Article::first();
$article->comments->count();
```

In this example, `$article->comments` will be executing a new query, as relationship accessors act differently if the relationship has been loaded or not. In this case, it hasn't been loaded, so `$article->comments` returns a `Builder` instance instead of a `Collection`, so finishing the query will execute a new query.

Finally, example three - `Collection` access with `comments` property:

```
$article = Article::with(["comments"])->first();
$article->comments->count();
```

In this last example, `$article->comments` has been specified as loaded via the `->with(["comments"])` clause, so it is a `Collection`, and not a `Builder` instance. For this reason, calling `->count()` is using the [`Collection` count method](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/collections#method-count), and **does not perform an additional query**

Comment: I see! That's interesting. So instead of `$submissions = Submission::orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->paginate(40);` I should do `$submissions = Submission::with(["comments"])->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->paginate(40);` ?

I have a question, however! Since I also have `comments` method in my model, how does blade know when to perform an additional query and when not to?

Comment: The `public function comments()` is in your model is specifying how the relationship works; until you actually use it, it does nothing. But to answer your question, if you remove the `->count()` method, and do a `dd()` on what's left, you'll see what it is, either a `Builder` or a `Collection`. For example: `dd($article->comments())` will always be `Builder`, while `dd($article->comments)` can be either a `Builder` or `Collection`, depending on if you've used `->with(["comments"])`, or `->load("comments")`, etc.